# Is there a bitcoin exchange accepting SEPA transfers?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox, wire-transfers

Since mt.gox [had to close](https://mtgox.com/press_release_20111021.html) its european office, is there any other exchange accepting SEPA transfers?

Sending a wire to the HK office costs much more than a SEPA transfer to me, and I'd like to avoid that extra expense if possible.

Comment: You are talking about SEPA transfers, right?

Comment: UPDATE: Mt. Gox now accepts SEPA transfers again, provided you become a "verified user".

Comment: This question is out of date, and neither the question nor the purported answers specify what currency is to be transferred or traded. The advice given in the answers here is dangerously out of date. Some of the exchanges do not exist anymore. Others still have websites, but they are not active. If EUR is to be transferred, one can consider Bitstamp or BTC-E. However, they will convert to USD. Mt. Gox in my opinion is unusable. Again, without further info on what you are trying to do, it is impossible to answer your question, and the answers here do not do it either.

Comment: This question and its answers are outdated now, I'd close it as too localised.


Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Comment: @Lohoris I agree - have voted same

Comment: @Murch I disagree with the duplicate, it's definitely **not** a duplicate, it's just outdated.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT This information is now out of date - voting to close this question**

You could use [Intersango](https://intersango.com)

It's a well-trusted exchange that operates within the Eurozone (and in the UK). You see their [current fee structure](https://intersango.com/fees.php) provides SEPA transfer:

```
Country             Accepting deposits  Processing withdrawals
GBP (domestic)      Free                Free
EUR (SEPA)          5 PLN (1.23 EUR)    5 PLN (1.23 EUR)
EUR (international) 10 PLN (2.46 EUR)   0.2%, capped: 9.5 PLN min, 180 PLN max
<snip>
```

Comment: I tried it, and found it quite disappointing. They got a commission higher than expected (2.26€), and — probably due to the low volume of exchanges — the bitcoin prices are much higher then on Mt.Gox.

Comment: My fees for a SEPA deposit was 1.20€ today while still being advertised as 1.23€ on their website — also bitcoin prices were about 0.30 lower today then on Mt.Gox but are now just 0.03 lower.

Answer (score 3):

[MtGox](https://mtgox.com/) and [TradeHill](https://www.tradehill.com/) usually offer SEPA transfers, but right now they are temporarily closed. MtGox is in the middle of a court case and TradeHill is changing banks (which should be solved in a [couple of weeks](http://tradehillblog.com/2011/10/27/sepa-account-transition-and-general-announcements/)). Here are some other options:

- Intersango, like [Gary Rowe wrote](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/is-there-a-bitcoin-exchange-accepting-a-wire-transfer-within-eu/1961#1961).
- [CryptoExchange](http://www.cryptoxchange.com/) launched yesterday and they charge a [fixed $15](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=51457.msg614442#msg614442) for any transfer regadless of the amount.
- [Bitmarket.eu](https://bitmarket.eu). This is a peer-to-peer exchange so you must manually contact the seller to make the transfer. It is completely free to use and they have an escrow service in place to prevent fraud.
- [Bticoin-otc](http://bitcoin-otc.com). This is not an exchange per se. It is an IRC channel where people trade Bitcoins over the counter. It is a fairly complex system (you must use a GPG key for authentication), but I'm sure you will find reputable people there willing to sell you coins. See [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/how-does-one-use-bitcoin-otc) for details.
- [CampBX](https://campbx.com) is preparing a service to [launch in Q1 2012](https://campbx.com/faq.php).
- [Bitcoin Central](https://bitcoin-central.net/). Charges no fees for SEPA deposits, but a withdrawal fee of €15.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/) is an exchange located in Slovenia that accepts SEPA transfers.

SEPA deposits are offered at no charge, SEPA withdrawals cost 0.90€.