# Best place to buy bitcoins?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

I live in Europe and, because of that, I would like to buy some bitcoins with my savings "just in case". I'm a student, so I'm talking about between 500 and 1000 € (it is not much money, I know).

What I would like to know is a trustful website to buy bitcoins. I plan to have my wallet encrypted in my computer, so its not about the security of the wallet, but the security of the transaction. Is Mt. Gox safe? Can I buy there with euros? Can I avoid paying a fee?

I'm sorry if these are very basic questions, but I haven't found any similar question, and I think that newbies (like me) will appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for closing your first question ... it's not personal, it's just not useful to have two duplicate questions. You should find your answer in the question I linked to though. Feel free to ask any more questions you have ... there isn't such a thing as a "too basic question".

Comment: Don't worry, you are right. I didn't see that question, but there I've found this link, which I think answers to my question: [Buying bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins).

Comment: Since you are in Europe, you might want to take a look at this question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/is-there-a-bitcoin-exchange-accepting-a-wire-transfer-within-eu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally have a look at the charts:

http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/

A good rule of thumb to judge how much people trust a website is how large is the volume of transactions - the more, the better.

In all regards, Mt.Gox is safe, you can buy there in euros, and I don't think you can bypass the fees. If you worry about the last one, you can try finding someone willing to trade Bitcoins with you that you can trust (which can be difficult at times).