# Is there a US broker for Bitcoins?

Tags: trading, usa

Apparently, there is an Australian trading house, [Bit Trade](https://www.btradeaustralia.com/), that will trade currency for Bitcoins or vice versa.

Is there a U.S. equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a US Broker for Bitcoins.  Unfortunately, for now, they're still in private beta.  The company is called Buttercoin: https://www.buttercoin.com/  You can sign up for their private beta, but there's a pretty long waiting list right now.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this has a valid point since this isn't helpful yet.  At the moment, your best bet as an alternative would be either trading OTC with bitcoin-otc (See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/how-does-one-use-bitcoin-otc?rq=1) if you're technically minded, or trading on Localbitcoins.com if you're comfortable doing the trade in person.